# SimpleJdbcTemplate and null parameters

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm using SimpleJdbcTemplate and MapSqlParameterSource in the folowing way:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameterSource.addValue("typeId", typeId, Types.BIGINT);

List<Long> ids = _jdbcTemplate.query(_selectIdByParameters, new EntityIdRowMapper(), parameterSource);
```

When `typeId` ( which is a `Long` ) is `null`, then the query looks in the following way:

```
SELECT id FROM XXX WHERE typeId = null
```

whereas I would expect it to generate

```
SELECT id FROM XXX WHERE typeId IS NULL
```

I've [reported this issue](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5451) and the response was that

> You will have to provide the appropriate SQL statement based on your query parameters.

and as a consequence my code is littered with null checks.

Is there a more elegant way of handling null parameters sent to the `SimpleJdbcTemplate`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have a point - JdbcTemplate isn't a SQL interpreter, it just replaces your placeholders.

I suggest you construct your clause with a utility method, and concat it to the query string:

```
String createNullCheckedClause(String column, Object value) {
   String operator = (value == null ? "is" : "=");
   return String.format("(%s %s ?)", column, operator);
}

...

String query = "select * from table where " + createNullCheckedClause("col", x);
```

Not very pretty. Alternatively, perhaps you can configure MySQL to allow "= NULL", but I don't think that's an option.

Comment: Will it work, if namedparameterjdbctemplate is used instead of simplejdbctemplate ?